# What is the moment of inertia of a thin equilateral triangular plate about an axis through its center?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the moment of inertia of a thin equilateral triangular plate of mass $m$ and side $a$ about an axis through its center (perpendicular to the plane)?

I expressed $r$ as $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and $dm = \rho dS$  so I get:
$$I = \int r^2\, dm = \rho \int (x^2 + y^2)\, dS = \rho \int \int (x^2 + y^2)\, dx dy.$$

Now for the intervals, I expressed the height the triangle as $v = \frac{a \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and because I know the center of the triange is $\frac{2}{3}$ from the top point and $\frac{1}{3}$ from the base, my interval will be $y \in (-\frac{a \sqrt{3}}{6}; \frac{a \sqrt{3}}{3})$. For the $x$ interval it is just $x \in (-\frac{a}{2}; \frac{a}{2})$. When I evaluate the integral, I get: $$ I = \frac{1}{3}ma^2.$$

My questions are: First, is this even correct? Second, isn't there a simpler way to find the moment of inertia (using integrals)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to do the integration in polar coordinates. We can focus on one sixth of the triangle, with $\phi=0$ corresponding to a midpoint and $\phi=\frac\pi3$ corresponding to a vertex and the side between them described by $r=\frac h{3\cos\phi}$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\frac\pi3\mathrm d\phi\int_0^\frac h{3\cos\phi}r\mathrm drr^2
&=&
\frac{h^4}{4\cdot3^4}\int_0^\frac\pi3\frac{\mathrm d\phi}{\cos^4\phi}
\\
&=&
\frac{h^4}{4\cdot3^4}\left[\frac{(2+\cos2\phi)\sin\phi}{3\cos^3\phi}\right]_0^\frac\pi3
\\
&=&
\frac{\sqrt3h^4}{2\cdot3^4}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

With $h=\frac{\sqrt3}2a$ and the area $A=\frac{\sqrt3}4a^2$, and taking into account the factor $6$, this yields the moment of inertia

$$6\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2\cdot3^4}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2a\right)^4\left(\frac{\sqrt3}4a^2\right)^{-1}m=\frac1{12}ma^2\;,
$$

in agreement with the accepted answer to [this physics.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384336), which, by the way, shows a nice way to use symmetry to get the moment of inertia without evaluating any integrals.

From your description of your own calculation, it sounds as if you didn’t take into account that the limits for the inner integral over $x$ depend on $y$.

Comment: Thank you. But if I count the moment of inertia of one sixth of the triangle it results in $\frac{1}{12}ma^2$ and if I multiply it by six, it would be a different number. Why did you take the whole area instead of just $\frac{1}{6}$ in your calculations?

Comment: @LaurenSin: I'm not sure I understand your question. I calculated the integral over one sixth of the area and then multiplied it by $6$ to get the total moment of inertia.

Comment: I understand you counted the integral over one sixth of area  but then you multiply it by the whole area ($A$) (or inverse area and mass). I did it separatly, like I first counted the integral and multiplied it by $\frac{1}{6}$ of the area and mass to get moment of inertia of that $\frac{1}{6}$ of the triangle. And after that I multiplied it by six. But my result is wrong and I cannot see why. And I don't understand you last equation (why there is whole area instead of just $\frac{1}{6}$ when you do the integral for $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @LaurenSin: I'm still not sure what you mean. I get the impression that you may have misunderstood my previous comment, since you summarize part of it without mentioning the part "and then multiplied it by $6$". The only way I seem to be able to make sense of your comments is if you overlooked the factor $6$ in the last displayed equation.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand what the integral represents. Is it the distance from the axis of rotation? If so, then I guess I understand your calculations. If not, what does the integral represent? (obviously, I understand it represents just one sixth of the triangle but i mean more like is it the distance or the area or something else?

Comment: @LaurenSin: The integral is the integral of $r^2$ over the area of $\frac16$ of the triangle (where $r$ is the distance from the centre); so multiplying it by $6\rho=6\frac mA$ yields the moment of inertia of the triangle.

Comment: I get it now, thank you for your patience. I have a last question though. Maybe it is more for physicists but anyways. If i count moment of inertia of just the $\frac{1}{6}$ and after that mutltiply it by six, why does't it lead to the same result? For example moment of in. of a full circle is two times bigger than $I$ of half a circle. Moment of inertia of $\frac{1}{4}$ circle is four, times small than moment of inertia of a full circle. So why doesn't it work in this case when the triangle is made of 6 same parts. Why isnt the $I$ of the whole triangle six times bigger that $I$ of on sixth?

Comment: @LaurenSin: No, the moment of inertia of a semicircle with respect to the centre of the circle is half the moment of inertia of the circle. The moment of inertia of a semicircle is smaller only because it's calculated with respect to the centre of mass of the semicircle, which is not the centre of the circle. Here I'm calculating the moment of inertia of a part of the triangle with respect to the centre of the triangle, not with respect to the centre of mass of the part.