# What is the moment of inertia of a thin isosceles triangular plate?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the moment of inertia of a thin isosceles triangular plate of mass $m$, base $2a$ and height $v$ about the height axis?

[image: triangle]

I expressed $\,dm$ as $\, dm = \rho \, dA = \rho y \,dx = \rho (-\frac{vx}{a}+v) \, dx$

So I get:
$$I = \int r^2\, dm = \rho \int_{0}^{a} (x^2)(-\frac{vx}{a}+v)\, dx = v \rho \frac{a^3}{12}$$
This is true for half the triangle so to get the total moment of inertia I multiply it by $2$ and get $$I=2v \frac{2m}{2av}\frac{a^3}{12}=\frac{1}{6}ma^2$$

But this doesn't seem to be the correct answer. What is my mistake and how do I approach this problem?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700656/

Comment: Why did you replace $r^2$ by $x^2$?

Comment: I took a thin area element parallel to the axis (height) and the distance of this element is $x$.

Comment: No, it's not, it's $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which depends on both $x$ and $y$. Since $r^2=x^2+y^2$ is a sum, you can integrate over $x^2$ and $y^2$ separately, but you can't just drop the $y^2$ term.

Comment: @joriki Sorry for my mistake. I edited the calculations but my result still is not correct and I cannot see why can't I replace $r^2$ with $x^2$ (see image).

Comment: There's no $r$ in your image, so I don't see how the image indicates why you should be able to replace $r^2$ by $x^2$.

Comment: Well, because the distance of the rectangle is just $x$. Or differently said I feel like $y$ is just zero.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. I suggest that you show $r$ and $y$ in the image.

Comment: Also, it would help if you showed the centre of mass in the image. The line labelled "$x$" is not at the $y$ coordinate of the centre of mass, which is $\frac13$ of the altitude.